# How to make SQL parse this XML faster

Tags: sql, xml

The code below works but it takes 16 minutes to parse the XML from 36,000+ rows in SQL. Is there a way I could change the below code to make it parse the XML faster? I have updated the code below.

```
select c.claimid, c.adjuddate as lastadjudication, cast(claimedithistory as xml) as xmldata, ca.adjudicationattempts into #kb from claimedithistory ca (nolock) join claim c (nolock) on ca.claimid = c.claimid  where adjuddate > dateadd(d, 1, eomonth(getdate(), -3)) order by c.claimid

alter table #kb add primary key (claimid, adjudicationattempts)

create table #kb2 (claimid char(15) not null,lastadjudication Date not null,attempt int not null, id char(60) null, adjuddate date null)


Declare @claimid char(15)
Declare @lastadjudication as date
declare @xmldata as xml
declare @adjudicationattempts as int
declare @nextadjudication as int
set @nextadjudication = 1

SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT claimid, lastadjudication, xmldata, adjudicationattempts 
FROM #kb order by claimid desc

OPEN db_cursor  
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @claimid, @lastadjudication, @xmldata, @adjudicationattempts  

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  

    set @nextadjudication = 1
    WHILE @nextadjudication <= @adjudicationattempts
            BEGIN

                insert into #kb2 (claimid, lastadjudication, attempt, id, adjuddate)
                select claimid, lastadjudication,xmldata.value('(ClaimEditHistory[sql:variable("@nextadjudication")]/@attempt)[1]', 'int')  as attempt, 
                xmldata.value('(ClaimEditHistory[sql:variable("@nextadjudication")]/@userid)[1]', 'varchar(15)')  as id,
                xmldata.value('(ClaimEditHistory[sql:variable("@nextadjudication")]/@datetime)[1]', 'datetime')  as adjuddate 
                from #kb 
                where claimid = @claimid
                    and xmldata.value('(ClaimEditHistory[sql:variable("@nextadjudication")]/@datetime)[1]', 'datetime') > dateadd(d, 1, eomonth(getdate(), -3))
                    and xmldata.value('(ClaimEditHistory[sql:variable("@nextadjudication")]/@userid)[1]', 'varchar(15)') <> 'hsnprbatch'
                    and xmldata.value('(ClaimEditHistory[sql:variable("@nextadjudication")]/@userid)[1]', 'varchar(15)') <> 'TorresM'
                set @nextadjudication = @nextadjudication + 1
            END

      FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @claimid, @lastadjudication, @xmldata, @adjudicationattempts
END 

CLOSE db_cursor  
DEALLOCATE db_cursor

select * from #kb2
```

Comment: Could you provide some more info on the used cursor please? Does it fetch the XML Data from the DB? How many iterations are performed in the mentioned 16 minutes?

Comment: You didn't provide a db_cursor query so it's impossible to improve a query without that info

Comment: I'm pretty sure, that you do not need a cursor here... but you do not show enough. Try to describe your input and the expected output. Best was a *stand-alone* scenario ([Create an MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) with DDL, data inserts and what you expect to get out of it.. `CURSOR` is brought to  us by the devil of procedural thinking. Get out of this dark valley and enter the light of *set-based* thinking. ;-) There are cases where a cursor is the right choice, but these cases are very rare...

Comment: Sorry everyone for not posting the full code. Please find the full code now, I made edits

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just create an SSIS package that runs this in 3-4 parts (instead of one) whenever you need it and dump it into a SQL table? Then just call the table, it will be much faster than trying to do it all in a query like that.